# Node Server How to run

Tags: node.js

I've got my server, but how do I run it?  I want to see "Welcome to Node Essential Training".

```
var http = require('http');

    var handleRequest = function (req, res) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Welcome to Node Essential Training/n');
        };

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(3000. 'localhost');
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal, change path to the location where you have saved your server file let's say name of file is server.js just type following command in terminal : node server.js and press enter.

After that goto any browser and type in url as http://localhost:3000 and you will see the output.

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra braces in the end

Also rectify the last but one line

```
server.listen(3000);
```

now run your file as

```
node <your file name>
```

You can see your site at http://localhost:3000

Comment: Okay, do you mean the bracket after (3000. 'localhost');?

Comment: Okay, do you mean the bracket after (3000. 'localhost');?

Comment: yes that is an additional bracket. and the other mistake is where you are using `server.listen` . You are trying to append the port with the server name. Instead they should be two separate parameters.